# how to extract part of a sentence to the left of one or more keywords using bigquery regexp_extract

Tags: regex, re2

I want to return the text to the left of department of, school of
to return
pomona college
rutgers college

I am trying to get it to work where I can pass in multile options.
ie split on "school of" or "department of"
I have tried the | OR operator in the line before_words_or but I am doing something wrong.

`regexp_extract(institute_name,r'^(.*)department of|school of',1,1)`

If there is no "school of" or "department of" in the institute_name it should return the institute_name

```
with t1 as 
(
    select 'pomona college department of chemistry' institute_name,
    union all select 'rutgers college school of engineering chemical engineering' 
)

select 
regexp_extract(institute_name,r'^(.*)department of',1,1) before_words1,
regexp_extract(institute_name,r'^(.*)school of',1,1) before_words2,
regexp_extract(institute_name,r'^(.*)department of|school of',1,1) before_words_or
from t1;
```

Actual result

| before_words1 | before_words2 | before_words_or |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pomona college |  | pomona college |
|  | rutgers college |  |

Desired result

| before_words1 | before_words2 | before_words_or |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pomona college | pomona college department of chemistry' institute_name | pomona college |
| rutgers college school of engineering chemical engineering | rutgers college | rutgers college |

Comment: Try `r'^(.*?)\s*(?:department of|school of)'`

Comment: That worked great could you explain the answer?

Comment: I posted it below. Please note the difference between the capturing and the non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'^(.*?)\s*(?:department|school)\s+of'
```

Or, with a word boundary to make sure `of` is matched as a whole word:

```py
r'^(.*?)\s*(?:department|school)\s+of\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSLlvd/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:department|school)` - a non-capturing group that matches either `department` or (`|`) `school`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `of` - an `of` word
- `\b` - a word boundary.